# How do I run code from `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b...` without disclosing the code itself

Tags: compilation, google-colaboratory, ipynb

How do I run code from url like `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b...` **without disclosing the code** itself ? Is there a way around it ?